# Need Help Replacing Item In List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a program in python bees,lowers, and trees at different locations and I want the bees to be able to move. However, when I run my program, it always gets stuck because of a type error. Could somebody please explain to me what is causing the issue and how to fix it. Also, I am a complete beginner to programming so any tips on how to make my code faster or more logical would be gladly accepted. The code to the program is below:

```
import random


wb0,wb1,wb2,wb3,wb4,wb5,wb6,wb7,wb8,wb9 = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

worker_bees = [wb0,wb1,wb2,wb3,wb4,wb5,wb6,wb7,wb8,wb9]


f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14 = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

flowers = [f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14]


t0,t1,t2,t3,t4 = [],[],[],[],[]

trees = [t0,t1,t2,t3,t4]


def world_generate():


    def worker_bee_spawn():

        x = 0
        i = 0

        while i < 10:

            worker_bees[x] = (random.randrange(0,100), random.randrange(0,100))

            x += 1
            i += 1


    def flower_spawn():

        x = 0
        i = 0

        while i < 15:

            flowers[x] = (random.randrange(0,100), random.randrange(0,100))

            x += 1
            i += 1

            if flowers[x - 1] == worker_bees:
                x -= 1
                i -= 1


    def tree_spawn():

        x = 0
        i = 0

        while i < 5:

            trees[x] = (random.randrange(0,100), random.randrange(0,100))

            x += 1
            i += 1

            if trees[x - 1] == worker_bees:
                x -= 1
                i -= 1

            elif trees[x - 1] == flowers:
                x -= 1
                i -= 1


    worker_bee_spawn()

    flower_spawn()

    tree_spawn()


world_generate()


def worker_bee_movement():

        x = 0
        i = 0

        while i < 10:

            worker_bee = worker_bees[x]

            worker_bee_x = worker_bee[0]

            worker_bee_x += 1

            worker_bee[0] = worker_bee_x

            worker_bees_x = worker_bee  


            x += 1
            i += 1



worker_bee_movement()
```

Comment: Can you please post the (full) error with line marker?

Comment: For the love of everything, please replace the incrementally-named variables with nested lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
 while i < 10:
      worker_bee = list(worker_bees[x])
```

`worker_bees[x]` is a tuple,  so `worker_bee = worker_bees[x]` then make  `worker_bee` a tuple and  your `worker_bee[0] = worker_bee_x` will fail with:

```
  'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

To make it clear, `(1,2,3)[0] = 3` is not allowed, `[1,2,3][0] = 3` is allowed

And use `range` to create your lists of lists

```
worker_bees = [[] for _ in range(10)]


flowers = [[] for _ in range(15)]


trees = [[] for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: Padraic, thank you so much! However, I have one question, when making my lists, what's the purpose of the three brackets next to each other? Shouldn't it only be two? And what goes inside the bracket? Thank you so much!

Comment: `[[] for _ in range(4)]` makes -> `[[].[],[],[]]`

Comment: Thank you! It makes a lot more sense now! I didn't notice there was a fourth bracket at the end of the line.